# update scrapy spider while running

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using python scrapy package. Is there a way to update scrapy spider settings while the spider is running? I tried telnet console and update a setting by the following:

```
settings.set('AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED', False)
```

'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED' was True when I started the spider. However, after the above command, the spider behavior didn't change. Did I miss something? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy settings are loaded when the engine is fired up and cannot be changed on the fly.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you should consider tweaking [`download_delay` spider attribute](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) on the fly.

Besides, looking into [`autothrottle` extension source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e748ca50ca3e83ac703e02538a27236fedd53a7d/scrapy/contrib/throttle.py) can help you come up with more options.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to scrapy, so basically I am experimenting with different settings. So the AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLE can't be changed on the fly, but others like download_delay can?

Comment: @user4389295 project settings cannot be changed on the fly, but there is a `download_delay` attribute on a spider instance - this is smth that you can change.